# Result of 84 instead of 63 in C#

Tags: c#

Why do I get a result of 84 instead of 63 in C# when both of these code looks the same to me? What am I doing wrong and why?

First is code from Microsoft's c# Tutorial which results as 63:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int number = 1; number < 21; number++)
{
  if (number % 3 == 0)
  {
    sum = sum + number;
  }
}
Console.WriteLine($"The sum is {sum}");
```

And here is my code, which results in 84:

```
int Num1 = 0;
int Num2 = 0;
do
    {
    Num1++;
    if
        (
        Num1 % 3 == 0
        )
    Num2 = Num2 + Num1;
    }
while(Num1 <21);
Console.WriteLine (Num2);
```

It looks like that they should output the same number, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do they look the same? I don't think so. If you want the version that results in 63, use that version.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your code and it will you what happens at every line.

Comment: Hint: 84 = 63 + 21.

Comment: Another hint: The top one will run 20 times. The bottom will run 21 times - they are not they same

Comment: Yea I kinda realise that it runs 21 times, but they both run untill either sum or Num2 reach 20, I mean mine is "while (Num1 <21); And Microsofts is (int number = 1; number < 21; number++) . sorry I am really really new to coding, just started a few days ago

Comment: @KojiAmpedASH `for(a; b; c;) { stuff; }` is basically the same as `a; while(b;) {stuff; c;}` Note that the increment is happening at the end of the loop.  What you have does the increment at the beginning of the loop.  If you move the `Num1++;` to the end then they will be the same.  Also you should initialize `Num1` to 1 instead of 0 althougth that will not effect the result it does change the number of times it will loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the reason that:

- In While loop, the condition is checked after its process in the code block.
- Whereas in the for loop it is checked before executing code block.

If you change the condition in `while (Num1 < 21)` from 21 to 20, the result would be same. As in this case, the sum would be done in same number of times as in the `for` loop.

Comment: @KojiAmpedASH Mark the answer as `Accepted` if it is helpful.

Comment: It has nothing to do with when the condition is checked.  It has to do with when the incremetn is done.  In the `for` loop that is done at the end, but in the OP's `do-while` loop that do it at the beginning.

Comment: @juharr As per the default syntax for both `loops` and @Koji requirement, the main difference is the condition check. Which is in `for` loop at the beginning and in `do-while` at the end.

Comment: No the difference between a `for` and `do-while` in reguards to the condition is that `do-while` will always run the loop once.  So if the condition is true at the start then they are the same because after that first check it doesn't matter if the condition is at the end or beginning, because it's just done between each loop.  The increment placement is the difference and the fact that they initialized the variable to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: To be clear if they changed that `do-while` to a `while` and left everything else the same they would have got the same wrong result for the same reason and then it should be obvious that it wasn't because of where the condition occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop:

1. the condition is evaluated
2. the code is executed
3. the value is incremented

In your `do-while` loop:

1. the value is incremented
2. the code is executed
3. the condition is evaluated

The difference relies in the sequences things are evaluated between each loop.

The `for` loop will increment the value then check the condition.  In your example, the value will increment the value from 20 to 21, then the condition will take you out of the loop right away without executing the code with the value 21.

The `do-while` loop does the opposite: it will check the condition first then increment the value.  In your example, the condition will evaluate the value 20, increment the value to 21, execute the rest of the code and only then the condition will take you out of the loop.

If you want the `do-while` to behave like the `for`, initialise `Num1` at `1` instead of `0` and move the incrementation after the sum calculation:

```
int Num1 = 1;
int Num2 = 0;
do
{
    if (Num1 % 3 == 0)
        Num2 = Num2 + Num1;

    Num1++;
}
while(Num1 <21);
```

Comment: It's not where the condition is done.  It's the fact that the increment is done at the end of the `for` loop, but they do the increment at the beginning in the `do-while` loop.

Comment: Yes, the condition / increment sequence is important.  I just wanted to put the emphasis on what happened once the iteration reached 21.

Comment: But after the first loop it does not matter if the condition is done at the beginning or end because it's just done between each loop.  Note that if they change the `do-while` to a `while` loop it will still have the same issue and then the condition is done at the beginning.